# Seeking examples of workflow using git-format-patch and git am

Tags: git, version-control, workflow

I'm thinking of asking my students to use git for pair programming.  Because student work has to be secret, a public repo is out of the question.  Instead, each student will have a private repo they maintain themselves, and they will need to exchange patches using git-format-patch.  I've read the man page but I'm a little unclear *which* patches will be sent.  The obvious thing for the students would be **send all patches since the last send** or (if git doesn't mind receiving the same patches redundantly) **send all patches since the dawn of time**.  (Remember these are student projects, they last for a couple of weeks and are small, and **performance is not a criterion**.) Our best friend is **simplicity** and we are fond of brute force as well.

Can anyone give me a short series of examples that show two people, each with a private git repo, exchanging patches using git-format-patch and git-am?  Or alternatively point me to existing git documentation and/or tutorial?

Comment: git-bundle

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175961/git-keeping-a-project-synced-via-mail/2188030#2188030

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It works best if they can see each other's git repos.  git itself is managed this way (there's a public repo people can reference, and then they format-patch from there).  If people *never* see each other's repos, things are a bit more difficult...

One thing they may do is maintain a reference to the last time they did a format patch.  Let's say they start by just sending their entire tree (including .git):

```
tar cvf - mytree | gzip -9vc > /tmp/mytree.tgz
# mail /tmp/mytree.tgz
git tag last-send
# hack, commit, hack, commit
git format-patch -M -C last-send..
# mail 00* && rm 00*
git tag -f last-send
```

`git tag` in this form creates a "lightweight tag.  It's a sort of bookmark.  This will be an easy way for people to keep track of what they sent so they can send it again next time.

On the other side:

```
# get patches from mail and place in /tmp
git am /tmp/00*
rm /tmp/00*
```

Comment: sadly, they never see each other's repos---although they may be both in front of a coputer working on one of the two repos.  But this looks like what I was hoping for so it gets my up vite.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. It helped me in converting a messy SVN repository into Git. My experiences are at http://blog.orfjackal.net/2009/05/converting-confused-svn-repositories-to.html

Comment: What about `git bundle`? Seems that is the better method for this workflow of sharing code. Unlike format-patch is is more a one-way communication workflow.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [`git bundle`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bundle) is the better option. Unlike `git format-patch` which is a one-way communication workflow, bundle allows you to leverage the same workflow you use with public remotes but are separated from direct access.

It is designed for sneaker-nets and would be perfect for students to save to USB or email bundles.

patches are more for submit for approval by a project lead style of communicating.