# Git or svn on windows server 2003

Tags: git, svn, version-control

I was wondering if anyone has any experience on getting a git server working on windows server 2003? Is there an easy solution to get it up and running? If not is there any good alternatives out there?

It ideally has to be free but willing to pay. It is only for a small team (3 users) but we desperately need source control!

We need to host it on our windows server as this is where are sites/code is kept!

I have previous experience with git but not with setting up my own server so an point in the right direction would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Why does it matter that the site is kept on the same server?  Why not use bitbucket private repos? Free for teams smaller than 5.

Comment: At the moment we have a development and a live site as expected. How would we (from git) update the relevant site when the code is actually hosted on the bit bucket site?

Comment: ftp, sftp, ssh, any program that can "synchronize" folders. Develop locally, push your code to test, test, push your code to production.

Comment: @BenThomas What did you end up using? I was going to try installing [GitHub for Windows](http://windows.github.com/) on Windows Server 2003 (used by a client) but it appears that it may not be supported. I was going to try anyway but I'm hesitant as I only have a live production server to work with. Did you find solution you're happy with?

Answer (score 2):

From my experience, the easiest way to get a Git server on a Windows machine is to run a virtual Linux server, and then use something like Gitolite. There's [GitStack](http://gitstack.com/pricing/) which is a proprietary package that allows two users for free, but charges for more than that.

I'm more familiar with the Subversion servers for Windows. Maybe someone more familiar with Git can explain the Git on Windows server options.

Meanwhile, here are just a few of the Subversion on Windows options.:

- SVNSERVE

  - Subversion comes with `svnserve` which is a lightweight server that uses it's own protocol. It's fast and easy to install on Windows as a [Windows service](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-serversetup-svnserve.html).
- HTTP

  - There are two well known GUI Windows Subversion servers out there: [VisualSVN](http://www.visualsvn.com) and [UberSVN](http://www.wandisco.com/ubersvn/download). Both of these are proprietary servers, but are free as long as you don't use any *advanced features* (like tying your repository to LDAP). Both have GUI interfaces which make it quick and easy to setup.
  - If you're more of a brave sole, you can get the CollabNet's [Subversion Edge](http://www.open.collab.net/nonav/go/csvne2_r2a/faq.html) package which is entirely open source. It's a bit more work, but it's completely open source. CollabNet gives you an Apache httpd server that's compiled to work as a Subversion server with all the required modules. Setup is a bit more complex than the others, but it's not something a developer can't easily do. The big advantage is that you can do things like integrate LDAP or Active Directory or use secure certificates (https), so your Subversion commits and updates aren't sent plain text over the network without paying extra. Just be prepared to open the back and [scout around for user serviceable parts](http://blog.makezine.com/2005/08/23/no-user-serviceable-parts/).

Then again, you can share Git repositories back and forth with each other without even having a server. You can use things like [email and Dropbox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2175961/368630) to share updates to the repository with each other. It's one of the big advantages Git has have since it is a distributed version control system.