# git - commit only differences?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I'm having a blast of a time with a project that's hosted on Bitbucket. However, I'm only connected as external user and thus make a new branch, push, and create a PR with my changes that their reviewer then need to merge.

But... Since they've made this awesome thought of making a whole backup of the project and host it as `/_old_project` on Bitbucket, I quickly get the infamous 2GB warning and can't push my changes anymore.

Is there some way to only git commit/push my ***changes only*** and not the whole code including my changes **and** the backup code? Or is there some way to only clone parts of the repo?

Cheers!

Comment: You can do a shallow clone? Not sure if that would help. It's normally better to leave large files outside of git or use something like git-lfs.

Comment: Aren't forks accounted for the original owner? I've heard they are so in github. If you cannot push to a fresh done fork, then you probably should fallback to sending patches or [bundles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2175961/git-keeping-a-project-synced-via-mail)

Comment: @max630: It's monday, and the office is out of coffee. I guess that would be the optimal solution, if one wants to keep using best practice by making PRs that are reviewed. Thanks.